# I want to join two dataframes in pandas but with potentially different columns providing the keys since the data is imperfect/dirty

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets that I want to join but the data is dirty, there is no single column that can act as a perfect key.

```
df_supplier = pd.DataFrame({
    "Company":["Company A", "Company B", "Company C"], 
    "Supplier_Website":["www.companya.ie", "www.companyb.ie", "www.companyc.ie"], 
    "Supplier_Telephones":["047 72451", "01 298 8330", "042 971 7900 087 222 2222"]})
    
df_installer = pd.DataFrame({
    "Company":["Company A", "Company-B", "Company-C"], 
    "Installer_Name":["jack", "peter", "helen"], 
    "Surname":["himself", "himself", "herself"], 
    "Email":["jack@companya.ie", "peter@companyb.ie", "helen@gmail.com"], 
    "Installer_Telephone":["0123 456 789", "0123 789 456", "0156 234 789"], 
    "Installer_Mobile":["Number1", "Number2", "087 222 2222"]})
```

In the data frames above the Company column does not always match perfectly "Company B" != "Company-B". Note that these differences could be anything, missing letters/spaces/capitals, data quality is terrible.
There are two further ways to merge/join the data frames.

1. If the domain of the website = domain of the e-mail address (for company B)
2. If the "Installer Mobile" is in the "Supplier_Telephones" column

What I want as a result, in the end, is the equivalent of the following

```
df_combined = pd.DataFrame({
    "Supplier_Company":["Company A", "Company B", "Company C"], 
    "Supplier_Website":["www.companya.ie", "www.companyb.ie", "www.companyc.ie"], 
    "Supplier_Telephones":["047 72451", "01 298 8330", "042 971 7900 087 222 2222"],
    "Installer_Name":["jack", "peter", "helen"], 
    "Surname":["himself", "himself", "herself"], 
    "Email":["jack@companya.ie", "peter@companyb.ie", "helen@gmail.com"], 
    "Installer_Telephone":["0123 456 789", "0123 789 456", "0156 234 789"], 
    "Installer_Mobile":["Number1", "Number2", "087 222 2222"]})
```

So it's a kind of IF(companies match OR domains match OR mobile number isin) then merge) but I'll be danged if I can see how to approach it best.

I'm assuming that Company names, domain names, and phone numbers are unique for any given company.

I'm thinking to add the finally desired columns manually and then iterate over df_supplier, do up to three searches in df_installer and then when a match is found anywhere, copy the values into df_combined.

But I feel that's very non-pythonic (just a feeling).

Any thoughts (or perfectly working code) gratefully received / Colm

Comment: Ah yes, and as I find matches, I remove the rows matched from df_installer so that at the end I also have a list of installers where there is no match with a supplier.

Comment: For `Company B`, the domain ids don't match. df_supplier has `companyb.ie` while df_installer has `companyb.com`. Are you expecting the `companyb` value to match excluding the `.ie` and `.com` ?

Comment: Thanks , Joe Ferndz, corrected in the question, i'm assuming the domain in the web address and the email address is the same.

Comment: Great. I also matched the middle part but i think it is best to match the full domain. Just need to fix a few things for the phone number as I need to match two of them. I will post the answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added comments in the code to help you understand how I am doing the data cleansing and matching the data.

As @igrinis and @Ukrainian-serge mentioned, you can try and use fuzzywuzzy module to do the match. However, you can also try to do this by stripping out characters that are not important and matching on the ones that are important. For the telephone numbers, you just need to check if the number is part of the Supplier phone number. To do that check, strip all non digit characters. Then do a check using substring match.

Here are the steps I took to get the data matched between Supplier and Installer DataFrames.

1. Step 1: Setup an empty dataframe to store the final results
2. Step 2: Cleanse the data in the Supplier and Installer DataFrames
3. Step 3: Match on Company Name. Exclude matches records from
   Installer DataFrame
4. Step 4: Match on Domain Name. Exclude matches records from Installer
   DataFrame
5. Step 5: Match on Installer Telephone Number. Exclude matches records
   from Installer DataFrame
6. Step 6: Match on Installer Mobile Number. Exclude matches records
   from Installer DataFrame
7. Step 7: Now that you have matched against Company Name, Domain Name,
   Installer Telephone Number, and Installer Mobile Number, remove
   unwanted columns from Supplier and Installer DataFrames
8. Step 8: Print the results of the Final matched DataFrame, and Final
   unmatched DataFrame

The full code is as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df_supplier = pd.DataFrame({
    "Company":["Company A", "Company X", "Company Y", "Company D", "Company E"], 
    "Supplier_Website":["www.companya.ie", "www.companyb.ie", "www.companyc.ie", "www.companyd.ie", "www.companye.ie"], 
    "Supplier_Telephones":["047-72451", "(01).298.8330", "042 971 7900 087 222 2222", "047 12354", "(01).287.8335"]})
    
df_installer = pd.DataFrame({
    "Company":["Company A", "Company-B", "Company-C", "Company-Z", "Company-F"], 
    "Installer_Name":["jack", "peter", "helen", "susan","emily"], 
    "Surname":["himself", "himself", "herself", "herself","herself"], 
    "Email":["jack@companya.com", "peter@companyb.ie", "helen@gmail.com", "susan@yahoo.com","emily@herself.ie"], 
    "Installer_Telephone":["0123 456 789", "0123 789 456", "0156 234 789", "047 123 54", "012 345 678"], 
    "Installer_Mobile":["Number1", "Number2", "087 222 2222", "Number4","012 345 678"]})

print ('\nThe original Supplier DataFrame is .... \n')
print (df_supplier)

print ('\nThe original Installer DataFrame is ..... \n')
print (df_installer)

#Step 1: Setup an empty Dataframe to store the final results

#rename company name as per final requirement
df_supplier.rename(columns={'Company': 'Supplier_Company'}, inplace=True)
df_installer.rename(columns={'Company': 'Installer_Company'}, inplace=True)

#Create an empty final dataframe with the required columns
final_cols = ['Supplier_Company','Supplier_Website','Supplier_Telephones', \
              'Installer_Name','Surname','Installer_Telephone','Installer_Mobile']

df_final = pd.DataFrame(columns=final_cols)

#Step 2: Cleanse the data in the Supplier and Installer DataFrames

#Step 2a: Cleanse Supplier DataFrame
#strip out space,-,(,),. from supplier company name
df_supplier['csname'] = df_supplier.Supplier_Company.replace(to_replace=r'( |-|\(|\)|\.)', value='', regex=True)

#strip out space,-,(,),. and leading 0 from phone numbers
df_supplier['sphone'] = df_supplier.Supplier_Telephones.replace(to_replace=r'( |-|\(|\)|\.)', value='', regex=True).replace(to_replace=r'(^0)', value='', regex=True)

#if you want to remove the .com or .ie from the website
#df_supplier['domain'] = df_supplier.Supplier_Website.replace(to_replace=r'^www.', value='', regex=True).replace(to_replace=r'\.\w+$', value='', regex=True)
df_supplier['domain'] = df_supplier.Supplier_Website.replace(to_replace=r'^www.', value='', regex=True)

#Step 2b: Cleanse Installer DataFrame

#strip out space,-,(,),. from installer company name
df_installer['csname'] = df_installer.Installer_Company.replace(to_replace=r'( |-|\(|\)|\.)', value='', regex=True)

#strip out space,-,(,),. and leading 0 from phone numbers
df_installer['tphone'] = df_installer.Installer_Telephone.replace(to_replace=r'( |-|\(|\)|\.)', value='', regex=True).replace(to_replace=r'(^0)', value='', regex=True)
df_installer['mphone'] = df_installer.Installer_Mobile.replace(to_replace=r'( |-|\(|\)|\.)', value='', regex=True).replace(to_replace=r'(^0)', value='', regex=True)

#if you want to remove the .com or .ie from the email id
#df_installer['domain'] = df_installer.Email.str.split('@',n=1,expand=True)[1].replace(to_replace=r'\.\w+$', value='', regex=True)
df_installer['domain'] = df_installer.Email.str.split('@',n=1,expand=True)[1]

#Step 3: Match on Company Name. Exclude matches records from Installer DataFrame
df_merged_temp = pd.concat([df_supplier.set_index('csname'),
                            df_installer.set_index('csname')],
                    axis=1,join='inner').reset_index()

#exclude all records in df_installer if found in df_merged_temp
df_installer = df_installer[~(df_installer['csname'].isin(df_merged_temp['csname']))].dropna(how='all')

#Concatenate the matched records to df_final DataFrame
df_temp = df_merged_temp[final_cols]

df_final = pd.concat([df_final,df_temp])

#Step 4: Match on Domain Name. Exclude matches records from Installer DataFrame

df_merged_temp = pd.concat([df_supplier.set_index('domain'),
                            df_installer.set_index('domain')],
                    axis=1,join='inner').reset_index()

#exclude all records in df_installer if found in df_merged_temp
df_installer = df_installer[~(df_installer['domain'].isin(df_merged_temp['domain']))].dropna(how='all')

#Concatenate the matched records to df_final DataFrame
df_temp = df_merged_temp[final_cols]

df_final = pd.concat([df_final,df_temp])


#Step 5: Match on Installer Telephone Number. Exclude matches records from Installer DataFrame

#Create a list of all Installer Telephone Numbers to check against Supplier Phone Number
tphones = df_installer.tphone.unique().tolist()

#Match records where Supplier Phone Number is part of Installer Telephone Number
df_supplier['tphone'] = df_supplier['sphone'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([part for part in tphones if part in x]))

df_merged_temp = pd.concat([df_supplier.set_index('tphone'),
                            df_installer.set_index('tphone')],
                    axis=1,join='inner').reset_index()

#exclude all records in df_installer if found in df_merged_temp
df_installer = df_installer[~(df_installer['tphone'].isin(df_merged_temp['tphone']))].dropna(how='all')

#Concatenate the matched records to df_final DataFrame
df_domain = df_merged_temp[final_cols]

df_final = pd.concat([df_final,df_domain])

#Step 6: Match on Installer Mobile Number. Exclude matches records from Installer DataFrame

#Create a list of all Installer Mobile Numbers to check against Supplier Phone Number
mphones = df_installer.mphone.unique().tolist()

#Match records where Supplier Phone Number is part of Installer Mobile Number
df_supplier['mphone'] = df_supplier['sphone'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([part for part in mphones if part in x]))

df_merged_temp = pd.concat([df_supplier.set_index('mphone'),
                            df_installer.set_index('mphone')],
                    axis=1,join='inner').reset_index()

#exclude all records in df_installer if found in df_merged_temp
df_installer = df_installer[~(df_installer['mphone'].isin(df_merged_temp['mphone']))].dropna(how='all')

#Concatenate the matched records to df_final DataFrame
df_domain = df_merged_temp[final_cols]

df_final = pd.concat([df_final,df_domain])

#Step 7: Now that you have matched against Company Name, Domain Name,
#Installer Telephone Number, and Installer Mobile Number, remove unwanted columns
#from Supplier and Installer DataFrames

#Also delete df_merged_temp dataframe

del df_merged_temp

df_supplier.drop(columns=['domain','mphone','tphone','csname','sphone'],inplace=True)

df_installer.drop(columns=['domain','mphone','tphone','csname'],inplace=True)
df_installer.rename(columns={'Installer_Company':'Company'}, inplace=True)

#Step 8: Print the results of the Final matched DataFrame, and Final unmatched DataFrame

print ('\nThe Final matched DataFrame is ..... \n')
print (df_final)

print ('\nThe Final unmatched Installer DataFrame is .... \n')
print (df_installer)
```

The output of this will be:

The original Supplier DataFrame is ....

```
     Company Supplier_Website        Supplier_Telephones
0  Company A  www.companya.ie                  047-72451
1  Company X  www.companyb.ie              (01).298.8330
2  Company Y  www.companyc.ie  042 971 7900 087 222 2222
3  Company D  www.companyd.ie                  047 12354
4  Company E  www.companye.ie              (01).287.8335
```

The original Installer dataframe is .....

```
     Company Installer_Name  Surname              Email Installer_Telephone  \
0  Company A           jack  himself  jack@companya.com        0123 456 789   
1  Company-B          peter  himself  peter@companyb.ie        0123 789 456   
2  Company-C          helen  herself    helen@gmail.com        0156 234 789   
3  Company-Z          susan  herself    susan@yahoo.com          047 123 54   
4  Company-F          emily  herself   emily@herself.ie         012 345 678   

  Installer_Mobile  
0          Number1  
1          Number2  
2     087 222 2222  
3          Number4  
4      012 345 678
```

The Final matched dataframe is .....

```
  Supplier_Company Supplier_Website        Supplier_Telephones Installer_Name  \
0        Company A  www.companya.ie                  047-72451           jack   
0        Company X  www.companyb.ie              (01).298.8330          peter   
0        Company D  www.companyd.ie                  047 12354          susan   
0        Company Y  www.companyc.ie  042 971 7900 087 222 2222          helen   

   Surname Installer_Telephone Installer_Mobile  
0  himself        0123 456 789          Number1  
0  himself        0123 789 456          Number2  
0  herself          047 123 54          Number4  
0  herself        0156 234 789     087 222 2222
```

The Final unmatched Installer dataframe is ....

```
     Company Installer_Name  Surname             Email Installer_Telephone  \
4  Company-F          emily  herself  emily@herself.ie         012 345 678   

  Installer_Mobile  
4      012 345 678
```

Comment: Wow, Joe. Thanks for the work. I'll have a look through it tomorrow but you do seem to be ticking the boxes. Thanks / Colm

Comment: Wow. Thank You. I didn't expect to get the bounty. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) module for non-exact string matching. Then you can get a score of matching each entry in `df_supplier['Company']` to `df_installer['Company']`. This way you will get a rectangular matrix. Same for all columns you think might match. You will get a set of matrices of the same size. Now you can add those matrices, and find a maximum matching values for each entry. This would be your best matching candidate. Now for the tricky part. After that set some threshold. If the maximum value passes it you most probably have a match. It's tricky because  the right threshold depends on how "dirty" your data is.

You can weight some of the matching matrices. For example, if you have exact match on the phone number, multiply the resulting score by (say) 10. This way definite match will override any other candidate. But for numbers non-exact string comparison will not work, so you will have to preprocess the data (like remove all non digits) and look only for  exact matches.

Comment: my thoughts exactly. filter out those that have low scores would at least downsize the data for the next cleaning step prior to join. an approach could be to select rows with the HIGHEST average of fuzzy match score across multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the idea is that something will match someplace. If it's not the company name, then it will be the domain name, or else the mobile number. The fuzzy matching and scoring would only be useful if I could only work with the company name.

Answer (score 1):

For our job, we will use some auxiliar dataframes, only with the columns we want, and in the case of domain, with substituitions already in place:

```
df_supplier_aux = pd.DataFrame({'supplier_index':df_supplier.index,'company':df_supplier.Company,'domain':df_supplier.Supplier_Website.str.replace('www.',''),'phones':df_supplier.Supplier_Telephones})

df_installer_aux = pd.DataFrame({'installer_index':df_installer.index,'company':df_installer.Company,'domain':df_installer.Email.str.replace('.*@',''),'phone':df_installer.Installer_Mobile})
```

After that we will build our three joiners that will hold indexes and help us join everything in the end - they are the company, domain and phone joiners.

```
df_company_joiner = pd.merge(df_supplier_aux,df_installer_aux,on='company')[['supplier_index','installer_index']]

df_domain_joiner = pd.merge(df_supplier_aux,df_installer_aux,on='domain')[['supplier_index','installer_index']]

# for phone we need an intermediary dataframe you can use any of the following lines (second one was commented out)
temp = df_installer_aux.phone.apply(lambda phone:df_supplier_aux.phones.str.contains(phone))
#temp = df_supplier_aux.phones.apply(lambda phones:df_installer_aux.phone.apply(lambda phone:phone in phones)).T

df_phone_joiner = temp.unstack()[temp.unstack()].reset_index()[['level_0','level_1']].rename(columns={'level_0':'supplier_index','level_1':'installer_index'})
```

The temporary dataframe used for the phone joiner basically is a dataframe with suppliers by installers dimensions with a bunch of `trues` and `falses` that tell us which suppliers phones list has a installer mobile phone. After creation it is filtered against itself to ignore false values and the remaining true values are unstacked. It is a trick to transform the two dimensional suppliers by installers array to a list of suppliers indexes by installers indexes. Note: one detail to pay attention is that there is some sensitivity to small installer phone numbers, if an installer phone accidentally is only `0`, all phones with zeros will be matched.

Then you will build the unified master_joiner. But to to that you will decide. Does it exist any precedence order? For example, if an installer is already matched to a supplier via company joiner, should it still be joined via domain and then via phone, risking being assigned to another supplier? It can be desirable or not, depents on the situation.

Using precedence:

```
# filtering domain from installers assinged via company
df_domain_joiner_filtered = df_domain_joiner[~df_domain_joiner.installer_index.isin(df_company_joiner.installer_index)]

# filtering phone from installers assinged via company and via domain
df_phone_joiner_filtered = df_phone_joiner[~df_phone_joiner.installer_index.isin(df_company_joiner.installer_index)&~df_phone_joiner.installer_index.isin(df_domain_joiner.installer_index)]

# we're building a master joiner using the filtered joiners
df_master_joiner = pd.concat([df_company_joiner,df_domain_joiner_filtered,df_phone_joiner_filtered])
```

Without using precedence:

```
df_master_joiner = pd.concat([df_company_joiner,df_domain_joiner,df_phone_joiner]).drop_duplicates()
```

And finnaly, the last join operation, starting from the supplier side:

```
df_merged = df_supplier.merge(df_master_joiner,left_index=True,right_on='supplier_index').merge(df_installer,left_on='installer_index',right_index=True)
```

We had first joined the supplier with the master joiner and then with the supplier.

Lastly, you can get rid of the two auxiliar columns:

```
del df_merged['supplier_index']
del df_merged['installer_index']
```

Comment: Hello Brunoff, thank you so much for your answer but I decided to give the bonus to the previous answer. It's very interesting to see your approach but Ferndz approach just fitted better with my way of thinking. Thanks again for your effort, your answer helped me to learn alot more. It's a pity I couldn't give two bonuses !